# What is the automation of project ? Please explain with an example

Tags: automation

Can you please explain me what is automation of project? How it is related with testing? Please explain with an example.

Comment: @shailesh-jaiswal: can you elaborate a bit? E.g. provide some background information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it is. It depends on the context, "automation" used alone with no context doesn't mean much at all.

Anyways, most likely it refers to a scenario like the following:

- You make changes to the code and then press one button. Then, the following happens automatically.
- Some program will check whether your checked out code adheres to the coding standards. If not then your checkout will be refused.
- Your changes will be built; if the build fails (or possibly has warnings) your checkout will be refused.
- A suite of various tests is ran; if one fails your checkout will be refused.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're referring to is [Build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation):

> Build automation is the act of scripting or automating a wide variety of tasks that software developers do in their day-to-day activities including things like:

- compiling computer source code into binary code
- packaging binary code
- running tests
- deployment to production systems
- creating documentation and or release notes

Answer (score 0):

It might mean different things in different context. It might be [Build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation), [Test automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation), [Continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and many other things.